# Can't get SOAP ET_Send to work with python, 'module' object has no attribute 'ET_Send'

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

I am using the FuelSDK to get tracking data about emails.
I tried to use the class ET_Send() but I get 'module' object has no attribute 'ET_Send' overtime I run it.

I looked at the client.py and it looks like it should work

```
class ET_Send(ET_CUDSupport):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ET_Send, self).__init__()
        self.obj_type = 'Send'
```

> https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Python

is the version I am using.

I tried using the ET_SentEvent and it works but it does not return the type of info I am looking for i.e. UniqueOpens, NumberSent, etc..

Comment: Really curious to know how you configured your python environment for ET

Comment: Can't seem to access mine according to installation